# Use a UIPanGestureRecognizer to rotate view

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to rotate a view using a UIPanGestureRecognizer? I would like similar functionality to the rotation gesture but with only one finger.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. But you'll need to do your own rotation math, of course. If you have a "center point" of rotation for the view already, that's especially useful, as you can track the angle of the touch input relative to that center, and apply the `transform` property of the view (or whatever) when it updates.

Comment: I do have a centre point, but im not sure about the math... could you explain further? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`.

This website should help.

http://chris-software.com/index.php/2009/04/26/animations-and-transformations/

From site:

```
# M_PI * 0.00 = 0° (original condition)
# M_PI * 0.25 = 45°
# M_PI * 0.50 = 90°
# M_PI * 0.75 = 135°
# M_PI * 1.00 = 180°
# M_PI * -0.75 = 225°
# M_PI * -0.50 = 270°
# M_PI * -0.25 = 315°
```

Comment: the link is broken, can you please update the link or explain the write down the concepts pls? especially if you have a center point of rotation